# Seeking simple visual unit test summary for Eclipse

Tags: c, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin

I have to shift development from NetBeans to Eclipse.

My unit tests used NetBeans' "simpletest" and resulted in a tree structure with red/green indicators for each test and a summry.

Can I use [NetBEans simplete](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html#addsimple) scripts in Eclipse and get a similar visual reult?

If not, what's the simplest unit test sytem with such functionality? Please not ethat although I can write test scripts in C++ to test my C, I would prefer not to.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably CUTE is close to what you need: http://www.cute-test.com/